# error import into android application with google places

Tags: android, api, google-maps-api-3, import

I was implementing the google places in my app. But when I created Google Place Activity 6 errors. I have sprung for the libraries, on the internet there is a lot of confusion. how to solve? I'm using the latest google api available.

```
The import com.google.api.client.googleapis.GoogleHeaders cannot be resolved
The import com.google.api.client.http.json.JsonHttpParser cannot be resolved
```

this is activity:

```
package com.example.app;

import org.apache.http.client.HttpResponseException;

import android.util.Log;

import com.google.api.client.googleapis.GoogleHeaders;
import com.google.api.client.http.GenericUrl;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequestFactory;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequestInitializer;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.json.JsonHttpParser;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson.JacksonFactory;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class GooglePlaces {

    /** Global instance of the HTTP transport. */
    private static final HttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = new NetHttpTransport();

    // Google API Key
    private static final String API_KEY = "MYKEY";

    // Google Places serach url's
    private static final String PLACES_SEARCH_URL = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?";
    private static final String PLACES_TEXT_SEARCH_URL = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?";
    private static final String PLACES_DETAILS_URL = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?";

    private double _latitude;
    private double _longitude;
    private double _radius;

    /**
     * Searching places
     * @param latitude - latitude of place
     * @params longitude - longitude of place
     * @param radius - radius of searchable area
     * @param types - type of place to search
     * @return list of places
     * */
    public PlacesList search(double latitude, double longitude, double radius, String types)
            throws Exception {

        this._latitude = latitude;
        this._longitude = longitude;
        this._radius = radius;

        try {

            HttpRequestFactory httpRequestFactory = createRequestFactory(HTTP_TRANSPORT);
            HttpRequest request = httpRequestFactory
                    .buildGetRequest(new GenericUrl(PLACES_SEARCH_URL));
            request.getUrl().put("key", API_KEY);
            request.getUrl().put("location", _latitude + "," + _longitude);
            request.getUrl().put("radius", _radius); // in meters
            request.getUrl().put("sensor", "false");
            if(types != null)
                request.getUrl().put("types", types);

            PlacesList list = request.execute().parseAs(PlacesList.class);
            // Check log cat for places response status
            Log.d("Places Status", "" + list.status);
            return list;

        } catch (HttpResponseException e) {
            Log.e("Error:", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }

    }

    /**
     * Searching single place full details
     * @param refrence - reference id of place
     *                 - which you will get in search api request
     * */
    public PlaceDetails getPlaceDetails(String reference) throws Exception {
        try {

            HttpRequestFactory httpRequestFactory = createRequestFactory(HTTP_TRANSPORT);
            HttpRequest request = httpRequestFactory
                    .buildGetRequest(new GenericUrl(PLACES_DETAILS_URL));
            request.getUrl().put("key", API_KEY);
            request.getUrl().put("reference", reference);
            request.getUrl().put("sensor", "false");

            PlaceDetails place = request.execute().parseAs(PlaceDetails.class);

            return place;

        } catch (HttpResponseException e) {
            Log.e("Error in Perform Details", e.getMessage());
            throw e;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Creating http request Factory
     * */
    public static HttpRequestFactory createRequestFactory(
            final HttpTransport transport) {
        return transport.createRequestFactory(new HttpRequestInitializer() {
            public void initialize(HttpRequest request) {
                GoogleHeaders headers = new GoogleHeaders();
                headers.setApplicationName("Test");
                request.setHeaders(headers);
                JsonHttpParser parser = new JsonHttpParser(new JacksonFactory());
                request.addParser(parser);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm also running the same problem here. So far I have solved the json dependencies adding the following library:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.google.http-client</groupId>
   <artifactId>google-http-client-jackson</artifactId>
   <version>1.15.0-rc</version>
</dependency>
and replacing:
JsonHttpParser parser = new JsonHttpParser(new JacksonFactory());
request.addParser(parser);
with:
JsonObjectParser parser = new JsonObjectParser(new JacksonFactory());
request.setParser(parser);
```

I'll let you know how to solve the GoogleHeaders dependency as soon as I solve it myself.

EDIT: It looks like they removed this class in release 1.14 (see this issue) in favor of HttpHeader. Change GoogleHeaders with `HttpHeader` and replace `setApplicationName` with `setUserAgent`, like below:

```
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setUserAgent("AndroidHive-Places-Test");
```